# In a time when starting to turn off the display of the activity, and then start it

Tags: java, android

I now have a activity receiver display information from service to send, receive after there will be no closed the activity, led him to stay on after completion of reception interface. The beginning want to once again start time time, to close out the activity, then open it again, service came from the information receiving display. Timing start broadcasting there through the log to see is received by the start time information, but because the activity received after the page has no exit, or not to move ... ...

The problem is this:

For example, every eight points from time to time to start at eight tomorrow, start, and then after a few hours, finished the work, the display of the activity will stop at the last page does not turn off, always stop until the day after tomorrow, when the day after tomorrow eight broadcast from time to time, the activity life has no reaction.

This problem I began with a solution is to turn it off and then restart, and now is in the service off him, after switching off, acquired the regular broadcast can start his ... Eight.

The activity with dynamic registration broadcasting, receiving and displaying service information  ( service's sendBroadcast ( intent ) continued to broadcast, until the thread to run over ); and the activity is made by another assignment activity boot, this arrangement the task of activity is true by regular broadcasting started.

Again, now want to once again start time time, do not shut off the activity, let him continue to receive display service pass information ... How to write ah.

CSDN for help with link：
http://topic.csdn.net/u/20120626/10/7d163b1d-d689-4dda-a7f5-b117e4c1f7e4.html

差不多解决了，原因是这个activity的mainfest里面有个属性是这样的：android:launchMode="singleTask" 改成android:launchMode="singleTop" 就可以了，不过出现了新问题，我要继续苦逼下去了……

Answer (score -1):

AndroidManifest.xml ：
android:launchMode="singleTask" → android:launchMode="singleTop"

20 reputation on Stack Overflow how to achieve?

Comment: You achieve it by actually answering questions. I can't even tell if you're trying to answer your own question here.

Comment: Could you read Chinese......Now I can't chat,So I want to have20 reputation。 Next I use Chinese to describe the problem, you use the translator to translate it into English。这个问题我已经在中国的csdn网站提出过了两天了，经过中国的搜索网站百度来到了stackoverflow，发现这里很好，所以我就在这里也提出了相同的问题，希望得到解答。后来通过我的调试，发现了这是因为activity的加载模式问题，So I just answered your own。